# Spring AMQP RPC consumer and throw exception

Tags: exception, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

I have a consumer (RabbitListner) in RPC mode and I would like to know if it is possible to throw exception that can be treated by the publisher.

To make more clear my explication the case is as follow :

- The publisher send a message in RPC mode
- The **consumer receive** the message, **check the validity** of the message and if the message can not be take in count, because of missing parameters, then I would like to **throw Exception**. The exception can be a specific business exception or a particular AmqpException but I want that the publisher can handle this exception if it is not go in timeout.

I try with the **AmqpRejectAndDontRequeueException**, but my publisher do not receive the exception, but just a response which is empty.

Is it possible to be done or may be it is not a good practice to implement like that ?

**EDIT 1 :**

After the @GaryRussel response here is the resolution of my question:

1. For the RabbitListner I create an error handler :

   ```
    @Configuration
    public class RabbitErrorHandler implements         RabbitListenerErrorHandler {
    @Override public Object handleError(Message message, org.springframework.messaging.Message<?> message1, ListenerExecutionFailedException e) {
   throw e;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Define the bean into a configuration file :

   @Configuration
   public class RabbitConfig  extends RabbitConfiguration {

   ```
   @Bean
   public RabbitTemplate getRabbitTemplate() {
       Message.addWhiteListPatterns(RabbitConstants.CLASSES_TO_SEND_OVER_RABBITMQ);
   return new RabbitTemplate(this.connectionFactory());
   ```

   }

   ```
   /**
   * Define the RabbitErrorHandle
   * @return Initialize RabbitErrorHandle bean
   */
   @Bean
   public RabbitErrorHandler rabbitErrorHandler() {
      return new RabbitErrorHandler();
   }
   }
   ```
3. Create the @RabbitListner with parameters where rabbitErrorHandler is the bean that I defined previously :

   ```
   @Override
   @RabbitListener(queues = "${rabbit.queue}"
       , errorHandler = "rabbitErrorHandler"
       , returnExceptions = "true")
    public ReturnObject receiveMessage(Message message) {
   ```
4. For the RabbitTemplate I set this attribute :

   ```
      rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(new RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverterAdapter());
   ```

When the messsage threated by the consumer, but it sent an error, I obtain a RemoteInvocationResult which contains the original exception into e.getCause().getCause().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the `returnExceptions` property on `@RabbitListener` (since 2.0). [Docs here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/html/#annotation-error-handling).

> The `returnExceptions` attribute, when `true` will cause exceptions to be returned to the sender. The exception is wrapped in a `RemoteInvocationResult` object.
>
> On the sender side, there is an available `RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverterAdapter` which, if configured into the `RabbitTemplate`, will re-throw the server-side exception, wrapped in an `AmqpRemoteException`. The stack trace of the server exception will be synthesized by merging the server and client stack traces.
>
> **Important**
>
> This mechanism will generally only work with the default SimpleMessageConverter, which uses Java serialization; exceptions are generally not "Jackson-friendly" so can’t be serialized to JSON. If you are using JSON, consider using an errorHandler to return some other Jackson-friendly Error object when an exception is thrown.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. Thanks also for the discussion with theMayer. Finally I decide to make like you propose by using the error handler. Initialy I had been done like theMayer propose, but it is more secure to have exceptions and in cases when I do not catch everyting the handler will assure to not lost the exception. May be I will put some of my code in my question, because I found that it is not very easy (I am new into Spring AMQP) so I take a time to find a way to do, and maybe it is not the right one. Thanks

Comment: Hi, now I understand what you means with your phrase for the exceptions that are not Jackson-friendly. Before I used the rabbit template with the SimpleMessageConverter, that serialize my java object, but now I would like to use it as JSON. So if I want to use the Jackson converter I can do juste new RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverterAdapter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter()). Can you give me some insights how to do ?

Comment: No, it's not that simple; as I stated above; you will need changes on the server side to catch the exception and return some special error object; you will then have to interpret that error object on the client side to throw it as an exception.

Comment: Thank you. I have implemented your suggestion. I create a custom object returned in error cases from my RabbitErrorHandler.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was :

On "serving" side :

- Service

  ```
  @RabbitListener(id = "test1", containerFactory ="BEAN CONTAINER FACTORY", 
  queues = "TEST QUEUE", returnExceptions = "true")
  DataList getData() {
    // this exception will be transformed by rabbit error handler to a RemoteInvocationResult
   throw new IllegalStateException("mon expecion");
   //return dataHelper.loadAllData();
  }
  ```

On "requesting" side :

- Service

  ```
  public void fetchData() throws AmqpRemoteException {
    var response = (DataList) amqpTemplate.convertSendAndReceive("TEST EXCHANGE", "ROUTING NAME", new Object());

    Optional.ofNullable(response)
           .ifPresentOrElse(this::setDataContent, this::handleNoData);
  }
  ```
- Config

  ```
  @Bean
  AmqpTemplate amqpTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory, MessageConverter messageConverter) {
     var rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
     rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(messageConverter);
     return rabbitTemplate;
  }
  @Bean
  MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
     ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
     objectMapper.configure(SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS, false);
     objectMapper.disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
     objectMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());

     var jsonConverter = new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter(objectMapper);

     DefaultClassMapper classMapper = new DefaultClassMapper();
     Map<String, Class<?>> idClassMapping = Map.of(
        DataList.class.getName(), DataList.class,
        RemoteInvocationResult.class.getName(), RemoteInvocationResult.class
     );
     classMapper.setIdClassMapping(idClassMapping);

     jsonConverter.setClassMapper(classMapper);

     // json converter with returned exception awareness
     // this will transform RemoteInvocationResult into a AmqpRemoteException 
     return new RemoteInvocationAwareMessageConverterAdapter(jsonConverter);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to return a message as an error, which the consuming application can choose to treat as an exception. However, I don't think normal exception handling flows apply with messaging. Your publishing application (the consumer of the RPC service) needs to know what can go wrong and be programmed to deal with those possibilities.

Comment: If you use java serialization, you can configure exceptions to be propagated to the client, where they can be re-thrown there. See my answer.

Comment: @GaryRussell - that's a pretty good answer. I still think "exceptions" are reserved for code that doesn't work correctly as opposed to service failures, the boundaries of which are often much better defined and should be programmed to deal with all off-nominal conditions as a matter of first-class code.

Comment: This was added at the request of the community, but I agree that it would be better to set up some protocol to return a meaningful error to the sender, avoiding this tight coupling.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Finally I decide to do like @GaryRussell propose. Your answer is also interesent and show me that even like that it is not a bad practice.